# Creating a view - Order with products

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im not sure how I would do this, I have an Orders class that holds users order details, address etc, and an OrderDetails class that holds the products id's and a Product class that holds all of the product info, cost, colour etc, how would I make a view to hold all of this in one view. Like Order 1 would have OrderDetails 1 and this would hold the products in this order.

For instance I want to display the Order Details, e.g. address, then beneath it the products in this order. How would I go about this? Also it needs to be related to the logged in user

Here are my classes

Order

```
[Bind(Exclude = "OrderId")]
public partial class Order
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Remote("CheckUserName", "Account")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required.")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Email doesn't look like a valid email address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Email")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm your email address")]
    public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }


    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }


    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool HasBeenShipped { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public CardDetails cardDetails { get; set; }
    //public List<CardDetails> cardDetails { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

Order Details class

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

The Product Class

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Colour { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductImg { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

So the order class would be related to the user, this would show the address etc, then i want the products related to the order beneath it

ViewModel

```
//From ORDER Table
public int OrderId { get; set; }
public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public decimal Total { get; set; }


//from Products
public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a ViewModel - a class that mediates between the view and the model.

Its very common to need to have view specific data generated outside of the model - combo box items etc, and for this case you should use a View Model. This data is semantically misplaced on the model itself, therefore you use an intermediate object to serve to the view and map this to and from your model classes - you can use a mapper such as AutoMapper to make this process a breeze.

See MVVM:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel

Comment: Thank you for the link, Im reading into it now and will get back to you if I have any questions if thats okay

Comment: Yes that's absolutely fine. Remember just put the data in there that the view needs, and map from your model classes. This is a very common pattern because it would be a bad idea to base your model classes on what your view needs.

Comment: Sorry just an unrelated question, just want to understand things a bit better, whats the difference in my classes from using 
public Category Category { get; set; }
and
public List<Category > Categorys { get; set; }

Comment: The latter is a collection and denotes a zero to many relationship i.e one product can have one or many categories.  Category Category is a one to one relationship. In both instances, none can also be represented - as an empty list in the first case I mentioned and  a null reference in the latter.

Its always wise to initialize the list in your constructor for 1...* relationships to avoid null reference exceptions.

Does that make sense?

If my initial answer was useful please mark it so.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks a lot, so in my ViewModel I should use public List<Product> Products { get; set; } to get the many products (or possibly only 1) to display? Im not sure how to get many products with 1 order to display

Comment: Yes, I would probably model it that way. You can access collections in the view easily using razor syntax. The viewmodel would essentially be the order and a list of products.

It is however also very wise to create a product viewmodel too. Remember, if there is data on the model you dont need, dont send it to the client - its a waste of bandwidth. Omit it from your viewmodel.

Good luck!

Comment: Im understanding the ViewModel and Views much better but im still at a loss with the controller for ViewModels

Comment: The controller talks to the DB and fetches Models, and passes these as converted ViewModels to the View. Sometimes you can just pass Model classes, but this is considered bad practice. Send only what the View requires.

Comment: I've added my view model in, Im not sure how to go about creating my controller now, I understand your description but im unsure how to implement it. Sorry about this simplicity, Im trying to teach myself how to use c#